# NGINX 1.4.7 from Ubuntu 14.04 vs latest version NGINX 1.8.0

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, webserver, spdy

I noticed that the standard version of NGINX in ubuntu 14.04 is really old compared to the (!stable) version on the NGINX [website](http://nginx.org/en/download.html), which is currently 1.8.0.
Why is there such a big difference? Is it recommend to manually update to the latest stable version of nginx on a production web server?
I was hoping to get SPDY 3.1 to get improved load-time. Is it worth the effort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx is constantly being updated and new versions contains [many new features](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES) which you might want to use and it's highly recommended to use latest available stable or unstable version. Nginx Inc. [recommends](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-8-and-1-9-released/) to use 'unstable' branch, and I totally agree with them:

> **How Branch Renumbering Works**
>
> The branch renumbering is part of our annual checkpoint process where we fork off a “stable” (no new features) branch from the “mainline” (feature development) branch. NGINX 1.8 was forked as the new stable branch from the 1.7 mainline branch, and the 1.7 branch is renumbered to 1.9. We are no longer supporting 1.6 (the former stable branch) or doing development in 1.7.
>
> In NGINX nomenclature, stable (now version 1.8) means that the feature set is fixed; only critical bug fixes are committed to that branch. Stable does not necessarily mean more reliable or more bug-free. In fact, the mainline branch (now 1.9) is generally regarded as more reliable because we commit a wider range of bug fixes to it, not just the critical fixes merged into the stable branch. On the other hand, any changes to the stable branch are very unlikely to affect the operation of third-party modules, whereas in the mainline branch the addition of new features might do so.
> To get a full view of how we do our branch renumbering (complete with pictures), check out [last year’s post](http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-6-1-7-released/).

I am unaware of anyone encountered problems when using newer nginx version than their distributive provided — considering both configuration issues and security ones, so in my opinion it's completely safe to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Can I use my config files of 1.4.7 on the 1.8 version?

Comment: Yes, just 'as is', no changes needed.